# Reveal items on scroll with vanilla javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing a project without jquery or js plugins and I am trying to create a custom script like the waypoints.js library. What i want to do is when i reach an element(half of its height) i want to add a class(with a css animation) and remove a class at the same time(class with opacity 0). I have prettey much done it but there are a couple of things missing there. First, if I scroll really fast to the bottom of the page the class changings do not happen and as a result they happen when i scroll **up**, which i do not want. Second, if i refresh the page then the initial class is added(the one with opacity 0) even though i refresh while I am in the middle for the page and the items are supposed to be shown.

HTML:

```
  <section id="about" class="section">
      <div class="section__square waypoint white" data-classToAdd="black" data-classToRemove="white"></div>
    </section>

  <section id="portfolio" class="section">
    <div class="section__square waypoint white" data-classToAdd="black" data-classToRemove="white"></div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact" class="section">
    <div class="section__square waypoint white" data-classToAdd="black" data-classToRemove="white"></div>
  </section>
```

JS:

```
 const waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.waypoint');

function checkpoint() {
    waypoints.forEach(waypoint => {

        //halfway through the element
        const addClassAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - waypoint.clientHeight / 2;

        const isHalfShown = addClassAt > waypoint.offsetTop;

        const elementBottom = waypoint.offsetTop + waypoint.clientHeight;
        const isNotScrollPast = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) <= elementBottom;

        if (isHalfShown && isNotScrollPast) {
            waypoint.classList.remove(waypoint.getAttribute('data-classToRemove'));
            waypoint.classList.add(waypoint.getAttribute('data-classToAdd'));
        }
    });
}


window.addEventListener("scroll", checkpoint);
```

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEgwvL
Let's say the white class is opacity:0 and black is the animation reveal.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function getOffset(el) {
  el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    left: el.left + window.scrollX,
    top: el.top + window.scrollY
  }
}
const waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.waypoint');

function checkpoint() {
    waypoints.forEach(waypoint => {

        //halfway through the element
        const addClassAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - waypoint.clientHeight / 2;

        const isHalfShown = addClassAt > waypoint.offsetTop;

        const elementBottom = waypoint.offsetTop + waypoint.clientHeight;
        const isGoThrough = window.scrollY > (getOffset(waypoint).top + waypoint.clientHeight / 2 ) ;


        if (isHalfShown && isGoThrough) {
            waypoint.classList.remove(waypoint.getAttribute('data-classToRemove'));
            waypoint.classList.add(waypoint.getAttribute('data-classToAdd'));
        }
    });
}


window.addEventListener("scroll", checkpoint);
```

I add class when we scroll over this element.
You can check my codepen: https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/dmZvXW